# Combining 2 data frames that together, create one social network into 1 larger dataframe in R

Tags: r

So, I currently have two data frames. One contains information on nodes for a given network and it looks something like this:

```
id age
01  14
02  23
03  52
04  41
05  32
```

The other data frame contains the information for the connections between the nodes and looks something like this:

```
id1 id2
01  02
01  05
03  04
05  02
```

So given these 2 data frames what I want to do is combine them in such a way that the resultant data frame looks like the first one but now has columns for every connection that the node has as well as a column that contains the number of connections that node has (assuming that it never exceeds 5). So it looks something like this:

```
id age  friend1 friend2  Connections
01  14  02     05        2
02  23  01     05        2
03  52  04               1
04  41  03               1
05  32  01     02        2
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Thank you for the pointer. I edited the post to clarify that a node will have no more than 5 connections at any given moment.

Comment: My solution would work no matter how many connections any of the ids has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
df1<-structure(list(id = 1:5, age = c(14L, 23L, 52L, 41L, 32L)), .Names = c("id", "age"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
df2<-structure(list(id1 = c(1L, 1L, 3L, 5L), id2 = c(2L, 5L, 4L, 2L)), .Names = c("id1", "id2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

require(dplyr,tidyr)
dff<-left_join(df1,df2,by=c(id="id1")) %>% 
  left_join(df2,by=c(id="id2")) %>% 
  gather("friend","friend_id",id1,id2) %>%
  filter(!is.na(friend_id)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(friend=paste0("friend",row_number()),connections=n()) %>%
  spread(friend,friend_id)

# A tibble: 5 x 5
# Groups:   id [5]
     id   age connections friend1 friend2
  <int> <int>       <int>   <int>   <int>
1     1    14           2       2       5
2     2    23           2       1       5
3     3    52           1       4      NA
4     4    41           1       3      NA
5     5    32           2       1       2
```

Comment: If I run this code I get an error:    in UseMethod("left_join") : no applicable method for 'left_join' applied to an object of class "function"

Comment: That's probably because we didn't use the same names for the dataframes. I've changed the df names to the same ones used in the other answer (df1 and df2). Now the error should be gone.

Answer (score 2):

It might be better to convert the second data.frame to adjacency matrix.

```
# DATA
df1 = structure(list(id = c("01", "02", "03", "04", "05"), age = c(14, 
23, 52, 41, 32)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

df2 = structure(list(id1 = c("01", "01", "03", "05"), id2 = c("02", 
"05", "04", "02")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

library(igraph)
g = graph.data.frame(df2)
m = as.matrix(get.adjacency(g))
m
#   01 03 05 02 04
#01  0  0  1  1  0
#03  0  0  0  0  1
#05  0  0  0  1  0
#02  0  0  0  0  0
#04  0  0  0  0  0

pmax(rowSums(m), colSums(m)) #Total Connections
#01 03 05 02 04 
# 2  1  1  2  1

#Add a column for age
mydat = as.data.frame(m)
mydat$id = row.names(mydat)
merge(mydat, df1, by = "id")
#  id 01 03 05 02 04 age
#1 01  0  0  1  1  0  14
#2 02  0  0  0  0  0  23
#3 03  0  0  0  0  1  52
#4 04  0  0  0  0  0  41
#5 05  0  0  0  1  0  32
```